# How to disable content negotiation and always return JSON from WCF data service?

Tags: json, wcf-data-services, atom-feed, content-negotiation

Let's say I have a northwind database and I use ADO.NET Entity Data Model which I automatically generate from the tables in database. Then I add a new WCF data service that inherits from DataService. When I start the web application, that runs the service I can request data like this:
http://machine/Northwind.svc/Orders

This will return all orders from order table in atom/xml format. The problem is I do not want XML. I want JSON. I think I tried all kinds of settings (web.config) and attributes in my application, but I still get XML. No matter what. I can only get JSON, when I use fiddler and change the request header to accept JSON.

I do not like the concept of content negotiation. I want always to return data in JSON format. How can I achieve that?

Keep in mind that I did not create any model objects, they are automatically created based on database tables and relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you criticize is defined by [specification of OData protocol](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/operations#RepresentationFormatsAndContentTypeNegotiation). OData defaults to Atom and client can control media type of the representation either by Accept HTTP header or by `$format` parameter in query string (but I'm not sure if WCF Data services already support this).

Comment: WCF Data Services in the version that I use do not support $format. I do not like this default behavior, but I will have to learn to live with it. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Well - content negotiation comes with HTTP. In any case, you could intercept the incoming request and add/overwrite the Accept header to always specify the JSON. There's a sample how to support JSONP which uses a similar trick, I think you should be able to modify it to always return JSON as well. http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/DataServicesJSONP.